# Trying to force a DIV to have a horizontal scrollbar via CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to make a div featuring thumbnails to have a set width (330px) and set height (100px), and make it so the content is arranged horizontally, so that a horizontal scroll bar is used to view the content.

Please see the row of thumbnails in the bottom right corner of my website: http://stevenlloydarchitecture.co.nz/building.html

I want to make it so that only four of the thumbnails are visible, and you scroll horizontally to see the others.

However when I try to specify width the thumbnails get moved below each other (as is currently displayed). I tried making a parent Div (with id "slider" in my example) to set the width and height, and have tried as many combinations of specifying width,height and overflow to the divs on the hope of forcing a horizontal scroll but nothing has worked and I am completely stumped. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the following css :

```
#slider  {
width: 330px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#thumbset {
width: 550px;// whatever width you want
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add the following styles to the `#slider` div to get only a horizontal scrollbar that scrolls through the images. Afterwards, its just sizing and positioning the `div`. The `white-space: nowrap` property tells the images not to wrap to next "lines".

```
#slider {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#thumbset {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: The upvote score now reflects the superiority of this answer for a wider range of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 14px">
  Here's a random text .............
</div>
```

see how this code works in this fiddle, it's  an easy way : [add horizontal scroll bar](http://jsfiddle.net/GCPDE/)